# R: Passing the index of the corresponding data frame (from a list of data frames) in a function within lapply

Tags: r

I have a list of 9 data frames `list_dataframes` read from files and a function `func_modification` to modify them. I would like to pass the value of `pos` the index of the corresponding data frame in list, so that individual rows can have their respective `dmv` and `method` names. How to do that?

```
dmv <- c(rep("MC", 3), rep("MSM", 3), rep("Random", 3))
method <- rep(c("COM-0.5", "IDT", "LB"), 3)

func_modification <- function(d, pos) {  
  d[,1] <- d[,1]/3600   
  d[,3] <- NA
  d[,3] <- dmv[pos]
  d[,4] <- method[pos]
} 

list_df <- list()
list_df <- lapply(list_dataframes, func_modification, pos=3) // Works
list_df <- lapply(list_dataframes, func_modification, pos=1:9) // Showing error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Map` to change the corresponding dataframes with each element of 'pos'

```
Map(func_modification, list_dataframes, pos= 1:3)
```

Or using `lapply`

```
lapply(seq_along(list_dataframes), function(i) 
            func_modification(list_dataframes[[i]], pos=i))
```

where `func_modification` is

```
func_modification <- function(d, pos) {  
   d[,1] <- d[,1]/3600   
   d[,3] <- NA #not sure if this needed
   d[,3] <- dmv[pos]
   d[,4] <- method[pos]
   d #return the data 
 }
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
list_dataframes <- lapply(1:3, function(i) 
  as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10, 5*20, replace=TRUE), ncol=5)))
```

Comment: Both of them worked :) I didn't know about the `Map` function before. Thanks for that !!

Comment: @jmkam Glad to know that it worked. `Map` is a wrapper for `mapply`.  It is very useful when we had to modify corresponding elements in a list with other corresponding element in list or vector or with corresponding column of a dataframe

Comment: Only a remark: lapply function here returns a list of data frames whereas Map returns a matrix

Comment: @jmkam Based on the example data I created, it is a list of data.frames.  `str(Map(func_modification, list_dataframes, pos= 1:3)[[1]])#
'data.frame': 20 obs. of  5 variables:`.  But you are right that `mapply` returns `matrix`
`